# With regards to Html helpers, does data access code go into the helper class too?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I am writing a helper class to query my Zenfolio feed, return and display the images. Right now this code is split between a viewmodel and code in my controller. I want to pack it up into a helper class. Would all the code go into the helper or do i still split the code among different class with the helper only responible for generating the html? I have googled but not found an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the MVC pattern there is a clear separation between Model (data), View (html) and Controller (what gives the Model to the View).

To answer your question, No. Load your models in your Controller. Display them in your View. Html Helpers should only generate html for your view.

You may want to consider using a [DisplayTemplate](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html), which allows you use the same View template for every model of a particular type.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do any data access from the view. This sounds like a good use case for an action, and reusing code via the `RenderAction` method. You can mark the action as a child action using the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute, which ensures it can't be invoked directly from the HTTP request, and return a `PartialView` result.

HTML helpers should really be used to generate HTML tags from data taken from the ViewData or Model (i.e. your view model in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Data access in an HtmlHelper is only pain.

I've had the misfortune to inherit a project that had ad-hoc SQL placed into the HtmlHelpers by the 2nd developer on a project.  The HtmlHelpers were beautifully written by the first developer, and the ad-hoc SQL pretty much nullified all of the time and effort put into having an service oriented architecture, having an ORM (the 2nd level cache became worthless), the unit of work pattern(transactions, worthless), and every aspect of design.  Eventually, this 2nd developer had to make larger and larger HtmlHelpers so that different elements could share access to the data.

This was originally done for a display mode, and editing was accomplished through a pile of ugly custom javascript.  All told, when the page rendered, it made 600 synchronous calls to the database.